# Configuration for Multiseat in Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: ati, multiseat

What would be the XOrg and LightDM configuration for Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on a AMD Dual Head Graphics?

I want to start independent LightDM instances on both monitors.

Comment: This unanswered question is about EOL Ubuntu 12.04. VTC as `not reproducible`.